# Horizontal ScrollView behavior on Android

Tags: react-native

I need to handle the scroll event when the user tries to scroll over the last `View` inside `ScrollView` on Android.

`onScroll` works fine on iOS, but does not invoke on Android when I try to scroll over the last view. Is it a bug?

Comment: Did you try the attribute horizontal? set it to true and try scrolling

Comment: Did you use flex:1 attribute in main container ?

Comment: Try different scrollevents like onScroll/onMomentumScrollEnd .It must be logging to some of them.